# JQuery quiz app - use <id> tag to toggle variable on/off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, switch-statement

I am writing a jquery phonegap quiz app and have a number of categories from which a user can select via checkbox. Relevant questions belonging to those categories are then returned. However, I have two huge switch statements to change the relevant variables from 0 to 1 if the checkbox for that category is selected and vice versa (this info is used to build a compound db query).

The value of the variable behind the checkbox is only ever 0 or 1, so is there a better way to do this?

My HTML is:

```
<h2>Categories</h2>
      <ul class="rounded">
          <li>Cardiology<span class="toggle"><input type="checkbox" id="cardiology" /></span></li>
          <li>Respiratory<span class="toggle"><input type="checkbox" id="respiratory" /></span></li>
          <li>Gastrointestinal<span class="toggle"><input type="checkbox" id="gastrointestinal" /></span></li>
          <li>Neurology<span class="toggle"><input type="checkbox" id="neurology" /></span></li>
      </ul>
```

My Javascript is along the lines of:

```
var toggle_cardiology = 0;
var toggle_respiratory = 0;
var toggle_gastrointestinal = 0;
var toggle_neurology = 0;

$(function() {
$('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) 
    {
        switch (this.id)
        {
           case "cardiology":
            toggle_cardiology = 1;
            break;
           case "respiratory":
            toggle_respiratory = 1;
            break;
           case "gastrointestinal":
            toggle_gastrointestinal = 1;
            break;
           case "neurology":
            toggle_neurology = 1;
            break;
```

etc. (which is cumbersome with 10+ categories plus an else statement with a switch to change them back)

I'm thinking of something along the lines of concatenating the HTML id tag onto the "toggle_" prefix - in pseudocode:

```
if (toggle_ + this.id == 1){
    toggle_ + this.id == 0}

if (toggle_ + this.id == 0){
    toggle_ + this.id == 1}
```

Thanks, Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var toggle = {"cardiology":0,"respiratory":0,"gastrointestinal":0,"neurology":0};

$(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').bind('click', function() {
        toggle[this.id] = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;

        //Debug:To check the current values : begin
        var s = "";
        $.each(toggle, function(i, val){
            s += i + ":" + toggle[i] + " ";
        })

        alert(s);
        //Debug:To check the current values : end
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks amit_g that's exactly what I was looking for! Nick

Answer (score 0):

```
var toggle = {
  cardiology: 0,
  respiratory: 0
}

$(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() {
    toggle[this.id] = ~~($(this).is(':checked'));
  });
});
```

$(this).is(':checked') returns true/false. Using the double bitwise NOT operator, you get 1 or 0.

edit: You should use an object to store the toggle states so you can access them dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for replying - will keep the double bitwise NOT operator in mind for future coding, not come across it before. Nick

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic variables?

```
if($(this).is(':checked')){
    window["toggle_"+this.id] = 1;
}
```

EDIT:

Shortened:

```
window["toggle_"+this.id] = ($(this).is(':checked'));
```